# const correctness with smart pointers

Tags: c++, polymorphism, containers, smart-pointers, const-correctness

I'm trying to understand better how does `const-correctness` work and more specifically, when dealing with classes whose members are based on `containers` and `smart pointers`.
I guess that the `const-correctness` property is the same regardless of the class members. However, since I'm having some difficulties to clearly understand what's going on,
I decided to ask you for advice.

So, here is the context. I've a `ShapeContainer` class that has as private class member a vector of smart pointers.
The `Shape` class is abstract and has the following virtual function `virtual float doSomething();` which is then redefined by its derived classes. Note that it's a non-const class function.
The relevant part of the code is given below:

```
class ShapeContainer{

    public:

        typedef std::shared_ptr<Shape> ShapePtr;
        typedef std::vector<ShapePtr> ShapePtrContainer;

        // .......
        const ShapePtr & operator[]( int ) const { return m_vect[index]; }; // const version
        //  ShapePtr & operator[]( int ) { return m_vect[index]; }; // non-const version
        // .......

    private:

        ShapePtrContainer m_vect;
};

class Shape{

    public:
        // ...
        virtual float doSomething() = 0;

};
```

Here are my questions.

Q1. Why do I'm allowed to call the `doSomething()` function in the following way: `int index = 0; float tmp = container1[index]->doSomething();`  (having `ShapeContainer container1=createBasicShapes();`)?
From what I understand, after calling to the `const ShapePtr operator[] const` function we'll get a `const` pointer to a `Shape` object, however the `doSomething()` virtual
function is **not** const. So, how does a reference to a const-object can call a non-const function?

Q2. By calling the `doSomething()` function as previouly ilustrated (`float tmp =container1[index]->doSomething();`) **and** by adding a `non-const` version of the `operator[]`, this `latter`
overloaded version is then called instead of the `const-version` one. Why does it is so?

Now, instead of having a `ShapeContainer` class, I've now a new class named `ShapeContainerInfo` that still has a `vector` but of an intermediate `ShapeInfo` class (that has a smart pointer as a class member).

```
class ShapeContainerInfo{

    public:

        typedef std::vector<ShapeInfo> ShapeContainer;
        const ShapeInfo & operator []( int index) const { return m_vect[index]; };
        // ShapeInfo & operator []( int index) { return m_vect[index]; }; // non-const version

    private:
        ShapeContainer m_vect;
};

class ShapeInfo{

    public:

        typedef std::shared_ptr<Shape> ShapePtr;

        // ...
        float doSomething(){ return m_ShapePtr->doSomething(); };

    private:

        ShapePtr m_ShapePtr;
        int m_nID;
};
```

Q3. When I call `float tmp = container2[i].doSomething();`, I get the following compiler error: `error C2662: 'ShapeInfo::doSomething' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const ShapeInfo' to 'ShapeInfo &'`.
However, when I add a `non-const` vesion of the overloaded `operator []` the compiler error is gone. So, why do I really need the `non-const operator[]` for `ShapeContainerInfo` and not for `ShapeContainer`?

Q4. If the `m_vect` `private` member of `ShapeContainerInfo` is set now as `public` member **and only** the const-version of `operator[]` is defined (not the `non-const` one), there are no compiler error messages. Why this? e.g. after setting `m_vect` to be a public class member: `float tmp = info.m_vect[i].doSomething();`

Q5. How could I correctly define both the `ShapeInfo` and `ShapeContainerInfo` classes such that I only need to define the `const-version` of the `operator[]` and still being able to call the `float doSomething()` function?

For those of you interested in the whole sample code, please find it [here](http://pastebin.com/0GupCyKX).
Clarifications, suggestions are always welcomed :-)
Merci!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: The shared_ptr is const, that doesn't mean that the pointed to object is const.  For that you would want `shared_ptr<const Shape>`.

Q2: Since you're ShapeContainer was not const, the non-const function was a better match, so it was called instead of the const version.

Q3: vector propagates its constness to its elements.  shared_ptr does not.  This is inline with the behavior of arrays and raw pointers.  The elements of const arrays are const.  The thing pointed to by a const pointer is not (necessarily) const.

<strike>Q4: Are you saying this produces no error?</strike>

```
ShapeContainerInfo info;
info[0].doSomething();
```

Please clarify, because that should be an error.

Q4: Okay, so you're saying that this produces no error:

```
ShapeContainerInfo info;
info.m_vect[0].doSomething();
```

Nor should it.  The vector is not const.  It's only inside the const member function that the vector(and all other members) are treated as const.

Q5: Make m_vect a vector of unique pointers.  Inside the const function, the vector itself will be const, and the unique pointers will be const.  But the objects that the unique pointers point to will be mutable.

As an example, the set function in this class is not legal:

```
struct Foo
{
    void set(int index, int value) const
    {
        v[index] = value;
    }

    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

But this one is:

```
struct Foo
{
    void set(int index, int value) const
    {
        *v[index] = value;
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
};
```

Comment: @ Benjamin, thanks. In regard to your answer of `Q3`, I defined `std::vector` as being `non-const`, or where exactly in the code, is that `vector` seen as being `const`? Do you've any suggestions for `Q4/Q5`?

Comment: @Tin: Since your member function is const, all members of the class are considered const inside that function.  I'm still analyzing Q5.

Comment: @ Benjamin, not really, it's when I've: float tmp = info.m_vect[i].doSomething(); In this case, I set m_vect to be a public class member and not a private one, and besides that, I've only considered the `const version` of operator[].

Comment: @ Benjamin, in regard to `Q3`, I read somewhere that it's usually not a good idea to return `objects by reference`. I don't find the link unfortunately. What do you think about this affirmation? Furthermore, in regard to `Q4`, so it means, that as the vector is `non-const` and also its elements, then we're allowed to called a `non-const` function, such as `doSomething`, right? If you could help with `Q5`, it would be great ;-)

Comment: @Tin: SO comments are not a good place for discussion, and the answer is not so simple.  Open a new post if you want to ask about that.  Answer to Q5 added.

Comment: @ Benjamin, in regard to `Q5`, there's no way to solve it through shared_ptrs, right?

Comment: @Tin: You could use shared_ptr.  I don't know why you would though.  Do you want the objects to have shared ownership?  They don't have shared ownership as they are right now, so I don't know why you would want to change that when you make them pointers.

Comment: @ Benjamin, what shall I add so that they also have shared ownership? Do you might have an illustration? I asked how to solve that issue using shared pointers for learning purposes ;-) I'm basically learning it by myself, so was a bit curious how to handle shared_ptr in this case.

Comment: @Tin: If you want shared ownership, then use a shared_ptr, the behavior will be the same as using a unique_ptr, you'll just have the performance overhead that comes with shared_ptr.  I suggested using unique_ptr because you originally had this: `std::vector<ShapeInfo>` -- There's no shared ownership there, so I suggested this: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ShapeInfo>>` -- But if you want this: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ShapeInfo>>` that's fine.

Comment: @ Benjamin, mmmm, I didn't get the last part. Indeed I had `std::vector<ShapeInfo>` in the `ShapeContainerInfo`, why do I need to add a smart pointer `vector<some_smart_ptr<ShapeInfo>>`? Which are the benefits? Is it all because of the `constness` vs. `non-constness`? It's not so clear to me, sorry. To me, one clear example on using containers with smart pointers is in the case of `polymporphism` as in the `ShapeContainer` class (the first one in my post). Note that, the intermediate `ShapeInfo` class has a `smart_pointer` as class member.

Comment: @Tin: Having a vector of pointers(smart or otherwise) allows the vector to be const, without the elements being const.  Technically, the elements(the pointers) *are* const, but the objects that the pointers point to are not const.  So even though your `vector<unique_ptr<ShapeInfo>>` is itself const(within the const function), the actual `ShapeInfo` objects are not const, which allows you to call your non-const function, `doSomething()`.  I've added a simple example.